# is it over-optimization to store secondary count information when recording vote totals?

Tags: mysql, database

I've got a table of votes (user_id,item_id,date) which records users' votes on items. The number of items on which users vote is likely to be in the hundreds of thousands, with users in the tens of thousands. I will need do queries returning the vote totals for these items regularly (items with top votes). To avoid continually summing all totals, it seems logical to keep track of the vote totals in the item table (item_name, item_id, vote_total).

On the other hand, doing this would mean constantly updating the vote table with the current total every time a user votes (lots of users updating the same row at approximately the same time), and I've been told that over-optimizing code can create problems. Is this something I should be worried about?

I notice this problem coming up again and again, for example I'll need to do the same thing with total number of comments per item, total number of views per item, etc. Is storing secondary information like this commonly accepted practice?

Comment: Unless there is a *performance test case that says it's required*, then yes, it is an *over-optimization*. As long as the model is kept clean, it keeps itself fairly adaptable: a secondary/cache table is definitely better than trying to work this information into the primary normalized data.

Answer (score 1):

Did your testing indicate that your queries were too slow? Did adding an index make the files too large? Did those indices not help performance?

Never go to the trouble of adding an optimization that you haven't demonstrated the need for. Your time as a developer is more valuable than that.

Comment: my query is very slow. on ~500K item records my query takes 2.7 seconds. This query already retrieves data similar to vote data (eg, the names of the friends of the session user who have voted on each item). Retrieving the votes I expect will make it slower still. I suppose the best thing to do would be to post a new question asking how to improve the query, and then consider optimizing it if it's still too slow.